# On updating to Debian 11 Applications Menu is missing and seeing error on attempting to add

Tags: debian, xfce

On upgrading from Debian 10 to 11 and my application menu is no longer present. On attempting to add it I see the below message:

```
Plug-in "Applications Menu" unexpectedly left the panel, do you want to restart it?

The plug-in restarted more than once in the last 60 seconds. If you press Execute the panel will try to restart the plug-in otherwise it will be permanently removed from the panel.
```

On clicking 'execute' the message repeats. On click 'remove' the message disappears but the applications menu does not appear.

I found the below thread on the XFCE forums where the OP has the same issue as me,  however no solution is provided. My sources list does not contain any testing repos.

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=14612

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade
```

and it should work again, it did so for me at least. You may also have to logout/restart.

In any case you, can always choose to access the Applications Menu by right-click.